Next.js Category page to Load More, Paginate or Infinite Scroll?
My Category blog page is loading up to 50 cards per category now and it needs remediating. Reaching out to ask what the best/quickest option could be using getStaticPaths and getStaticProps already implemented.
Display 6 category card items then Load More? Paginate or Infinite Scroll? Suggestions appreciated!
import getAllTagsOrCats from "@/scripts/mdx/getAllTagsOrCats"
import getPostsWithTagOrCat from "@/scripts/mdx/getPostsWithTagOrCat"
import SEO from "@/components/SEO"
import PostCardList from "@/components/PostCardList"
import capitalizeStr from "@/scripts/posts/capitalizeStr"
import MainContainer from "@/components/MainContainer"
import PageTitle from "@/components/PageTitle"
    export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const paths = getAllTagsOrCats("categories").map((c) => ({params: {category: c}}))
    return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
    }
}
    export async function getStaticProps({params:{category}}) {
    const posts = getPostsWithTagOrCat(category, "categories")
    return {
    // Passed to the page component as props
    props: {
    posts,
    category
    },
    }
}
    const CategoryPage = ({posts, category}) => {
    return <>
    <SEO pageName={capitalizeStr(category)} />
    <MainContainer>
    <PageTitle suptitle="category" title={category} />
    
        <PostCardList posts={posts} />
    <LOAD MORE BUTTON HERE PERHAPS? />

    </MainContainer>
    </>
}
export default CategoryPage

